# Azure machine learning repeated string

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a column in a dataset has many strings what i need a model that  scores or evaluate or get the percentage of how many times  the strings are repeated compared to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a frequency distribution of string? A simple R script can do it pretty quick. So in Azure ML, you can drag/drop execute R module and use script that is similar to the following script

> x=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D")
>
> summary(as.factor(x))

```
  A B C D 

  3 2 1 2
```